# How to include spaces in attribute names in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, attributes, create-table

I am having trouble creating a table in sqlite. In particular, I can't seem to make a table with attributes names that have spaces in them.

The following works:

```
create table Store(e varchar, t varchar, v int, s varchar, a int);
```

The follow DOES not work:

```
create table Store(“Name” varchar, “Type of Stock” varchar, “Distance between stock” int, “Date of visit” varchar, “Preference on Stock” int);
```

This also DOES NOT WORK:

```
create table Store(Name varchar, Type of Stock varchar, Distance between stock int, Date of visit varchar, Preference on Stock int);
```

I've tried using quotes around the names, both single ' and double " quotes but they both do not work. I also have tried the second command without quotes around, but that does not work.

How do I make it so I can use spaces for attribute names? Thanks.

Comment: You have curly quotes in the question. You need to use normal ASCII double quotes.

Comment: You are correct, sir. Thanks! Couldn't solve that one for an hour...